# comparison between pointer and integer error

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, char

Hey guys i have this c program working and i want to modify the printbooking() in order to print only rooms with a status of "checked-out"
so far i am only getting an error about comparison between pointer and integer....any help on how i should do this?
and also. i want to be able to search through rooms with the roomID and edit their details.Any help will be appreciated!
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
char BookId[7];
char CustId[7];
char RoomId[5];
char NumGuests[4];
char StartDate[11];
char EndDate[11];
char Status[20];
} booking_t;

int readBooking(booking_t *myStruct)
{
FILE *infile;
infile = fopen("booking.txt", "r");
char record[201];
char *token;
int i = 0;
while (fgets(record, 200, infile) != NULL) {
    token = strtok(record, ";");
    strcpy(myStruct[i].BookId, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
    strcpy(myStruct[i].CustId, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
    strcpy(myStruct[i].RoomId, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
    strcpy(myStruct[i].NumGuests, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
    strcpy(myStruct[i].StartDate, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
    strcpy(myStruct[i].EndDate, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    strcpy(myStruct[i].Status, token);
    i++;
}
fclose(infile);
return(i);
}
```

//this is the code that i want to print out only "checked out rooms"

```
void printBooking(booking_t *myStruct, int Size)
{
    printf("Booking ID, Customer ID, Room ID, Number of Guests, Start Date, End Date, Status\n");
int i;
for(i = 0; i < Size;i++){
    if(myStruct[i].Status[15] == "checked-out") //the error message points to this line
printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", myStruct[i].BookId, myStruct[i].CustId, myStruct[i].RoomId, myStruct[i].NumGuests, myStruct[i].StartDate, myStruct[i].EndDate, myStruct[i].Status); 
}
printf("\n");
}
```

//

```
void printMayBooking(booking_t *myStruct, int Size)
{
    printf("Booking ID, Customer ID, Room ID, Number of Guests, Start Date, End Date, Status\n");
int i;
for(i = 0; i < Size;i++){
    if(myStruct[i].StartDate[4] == '5')
        printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", myStruct[i].BookId, myStruct[i].CustId, myStruct[i].RoomId, myStruct[i].NumGuests, myStruct[i].StartDate, myStruct[i].EndDate, myStruct[i].Status); 
}
printf("\n");       
}

int main()
{
    booking_t booking_list[50];
    int Size;
    Size = readBooking(booking_list);
    printBooking(booking_list, Size);
    printMayBooking(booking_list, Size);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(myStruct[i].Status[15] == "checked-out")
```

`myStruct[i].Status[15]` gives the character at that index and you are comparing it with a string which is what the problem is.

I think you need to compare with the `Status` array itself using `strcmp`.

```
if( strcmp( myStruct[i].Status, "checked-out") == 0 )
// ...
```

Comment: if(strcmp(myStruct[i].Status, "checked-out") == 0) 

this gave me a segmentation fault  :(

Comment: check if `myStruct` is NULL for the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

`Status[15]` is a `char`, and you're trying to compare to the `const char *` "checked-out". I don't know what the "15" is for, but I suspect you just want

```
if(strcmp(myStruct[i].Status, "checked-out") == 0)
```

`strcmp()` is the string comparison function in C.

Comment: there was an error with the [15] (i was guessing i had to input it as it was a char)

Comment: -1 Your first sentence was right on the money, so I don't fully understand why you made the same mistake as the OP with your code suggestion.

Comment: i used your code segment and ended up with a segmentation fault, any clue on why?

Comment: Do you know for sure that `Size` is less than 50, and that all the strings you read are smaller than the sizes you've allotted for them (including the zero byte at the end of each string?" Your "readBooking" function is fraught with peril -- there's no error checking at all and a million things that could go wrong.